# Why "hash /bin/ls" does nothing?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, hash, terminal

Writing the command `hash` with some relative or an absolute path, whether to a file, directory or a to nowhere, it seems to do nothing.

```
$> hash /bin/ls
prints nothing ***

$> hash /path/to/nowhere
prints nothing ***

$> hash ../same/as/above
same thing ***
```

Why is that?

Comment: What were you expecting? `hash foo` just causes the shell to remember what `foo` resolves to so that it doesn't have to perform path lookup every time `foo` is run.

Comment: I know, "```hash foo```" return the message ```hash: foo: not found```. But when it comes to paths, it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

`hash` does a command search and remembers the resolved location. Part of command search is skipping it when there's a slash in the name*. Therefore, `hash foo/bar` does nothing.

Relevant POSIX spec:

[hash](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/hash.html):

> The hash utility shall affect the way the current shell environment remembers the locations of utilities found as described in Command Search and Execution. [...] It shall add utility locations to its list of remembered locations

[Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> If the command name contains at least one `<slash>`, the shell shall execute the utility in a separate utility environment with actions equivalent to calling the execl() function
>
> [...]
>
> Once a utility [invoked without a slash] has been searched for and found (either as a result of this specific search or as part of an unspecified shell start-up activity), an implementation may remember its location and need not search for the utility again

---

* This is incidentally why you execute a script in the current dir with `./myfile`: it's the shortest way to make the filename contain a slash.